# Global "Go to definition" in vim for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I've been using vi/vim since '97 for various quick edits and
administration tasks, but have only recently considered using it to
replace Netbeans as my ruby editor of choice. One thing I find
extremely useful in both Netbeans and Eclipse is the Ctrl+Click "Go to
definition" feature, where you can ctrl+click on a class or method and
it will take you to the definition.

Now, I've played with exuberant ctags and rails.vim, and it's close,
but no cigar. Here's what I want: by default in Netbeans and Eclipse,
you can ctrl+click a local method or class in your local rails
**project, but you can also ctrl+click on things defined in gems or in
the system libraries that are coded in Ruby**. Netbeans for example
parses all ruby files in the default system paths and makes them
navigable for you. If there are multiple files that define a method,
it will present you with a list and allow you to choose between them.

How can one accomplish this within vim? If it can be done, I may be
able to make the jump full time.

Comment: In what way is 'Exuberant ctags' not working for you. I've not used this particular utility but have used tag files in vi/vim for years with no issues. 

Are you telling your tags generator to search all the ruby code in your libraries/gems as well.

Comment: @SteveWeet ctags does not properly parse Ruby / Rails namespace, so methods in namespaced classes will only open the base class in the namespace, not the one that contains the target method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiple tag files in Vim as follows:

```
:set tags=./tags,c:/ruby/lib/tags
```

Using `g]` will give you options for multiple entries found.